# semantic-ui-react <Responsive> not working for <Table.Cell>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using semantic-ui react to render a table of data. My requirement is that when the page is on mobile view, I hide certain columns. I tried using `className="mobile hidden"` on the `Table.Cell` element but this doesn't seem to work at all.

Then I tried using the `Responsive` component like below but I am getting an error. Am I missing something here? Unable to find anyone else having this issue ...

```
  <Responsive as={Table.Cell} minWidth={Responsive.onlyMobile.minWidth}>
     {record.datapoint}
  </Responsive>
```

I get this error in the console when resizing the window...

```
index.js:2177 Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState, replaceState, or forceUpdate on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.

Please check the code for the Responsive component.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, this is bug :( I've created PR that will solve described issue, see [Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React#2421](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/pull/2421).

Code that you provided doesn't reproduce problem, the issue will be never occured with provided example. However, it exists :) The core problem is the unmount of `Responsive` component when it will be done by parent and `setState()` will be called on unmouted component. An example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/koql1pn5ro) reproduces problem.

Comment: Thank you for follow up!